# Add my program to "Complete action using..." list, when clicking a file in filebrowser

Tags: android, action, manifest

When clicking a file in any filebrowser the user usually gets to choose from a list of which app to open it with.

How can I add my program to this "Complete action using..." list, so that the file can be opened in my app?

I know this has to be added to the manifest somehow, but I can't find what to add.

RESULT:

I followed the answers I got here and made it work with this code:

```
<intent-filter android:label="MyApp">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="com.MyApp.action.EDIT_NOTE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*txt" />
```

Comment: Please offer a little bit more information.  What exactly are you trying to open with your app?  If you provide that detail, we may be able to offer you more specific advice.  Otherwise Jesus Oliva has it right---you need to add an intent filter for the activity in your manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of how to link to doc, xls or pdf file extensions:

```
<activity android:name="ActivityTest" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*doc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*xls" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

You can also create the filter for specific Mime types. More info: http://d.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an [Intent filter](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) to handle the MIME type of that file.